# How modify template successful purchase

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

when successful purchase, an email is sent that shows this
[image]

how to hide or delete that red mark in the picture, the SKU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to your theme and create folder Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order

then download default.phtml file

from

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order

then paste here

> Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order

in your theme.

and remove sku line from code

```
<p class="sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
```